# Bill of materials is possible in Excel?

Tags: excel, product

I use Excel to store information about purchased products and invoices (according ID, Item!, Quantity, Price(per), Date etc.). Every time I have to put the new information about orders into table. For example: I have an order. First I create new rows in table for each order. Then I purchase them and after delivery I can fill the rows. But sometimes I order the same item, but with different price and quantity or I should to order more, since last time was not enough.

Therefore, I want to create a "program" in Excel to organize them and to check the order status, whether task already done or not.

The problem is that I can't use the same cell for different prices. And reorder can be also not sufficient.

Any kind of help is welcome!

P.S.
I can do it in MS Excel?
Do I have to learn maybe MS Access?
Is there any freeware relevant for my purpose?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do if task is already done or not? Not very clear what you're trying to accomplish...

Comment: Hrm... It's a little bit complicated problem, hard to explain. I want to create a database in Excel, but I don't want to have a duplicate items every time. I want to see easily what I left to order, what I have ordered, incomplete tasks etc. In the same time I want to organize items. Something like a simple demand chain management tool.

Comment: As you can see from the table there is a lack in order (green, actually it should be red), so I have to order 33 piece "Bosch 2607019444 HM". In my first order price was e.g. 234, but now it's 240. So, I need to add a new information about recently ordered item. How can I combine a new and old price together - also quantity - without touching a old price and calculate the total price.